# how to read a specific txt from txt file and format it into a table using python

Tags: python, text-files, create-table

i want to extract specific data from txt file  like 'Port-channel2''vlan'column and put what is after vlan in this column.
**this is part of the txt file:**

- VLAN + IP address
  --------------------23
  Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
  Vlan1                  unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
  Vlan5                  10.26.95.33     YES NVRAM  up                    up
  Vlan20                 10.26.93.1      YES NVRAM  up                    up
  Vlan30                 10.26.93.65     YES NVRAM  up                    up
  Vlan40                 10.63.121.251   YES NVRAM  down                  down
  Vlan50                 10.50.50.54     YES NVRAM  up                    up
  Vlan60                 10.26.95.22     YES NVRAM  down                  down
  Vlan101                10.26.92.1      YES NVRAM  up                    up
  Vlan131                10.26.81.1      YES NVRAM  down                  down
  Vlan134                10.26.82.1      YES NVRAM  up                    up
  Vlan151                10.26.83.1      YES NVRAM  down                  down
  Vlan201                10.26.80.1      YES NVRAM  up                    up
- Subnet Mask
  -------------39
  Internet address is 10.210.130.10/30
  Internet address is 172.16.1.202/24
  Internet address is 151.151.151.151/32
  Internet address is 10.26.95.33/27
  Internet address is 10.26.93.1/26
  Internet address is 10.26.93.65/26
  Internet address is 10.63.121.251/28
  Internet address is 10.50.50.54/24
  Internet address is 10.26.95.22/29
  Internet address is 10.26.92.1/24
  Internet address is 10.26.81.1/24
  Internet address is 10.26.82.1/24
  Internet address is 10.26.83.1/24
  Internet address is 10.26.80.1/24
  ##################################################################################
- LAN Sheet55
  ############
- Access or Trunk with VLANs

---

interface Port-channel2
switchport trunk allowed vlan 5,20,30,101,134,201,381
interface Port-channel1
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
switchport trunk allowed vlan 5,20,30,101,134,201,381
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
channel-group 1 mode on
interface GigabitEthernet1/0
switchport trunk allowed vlan 5,20,30,101,134,201,381
channel-group 2 mode on70
interface GigabitEthernet1/1
switchport trunk allowed vlan 5,20,30,101,134,201,381
channel-group 2 mode on
interface GigabitEthernet1/2
interface GigabitEthernet1/3
ip route 172.16.1.203 255.255.255.255 GigabitEthernet0/1
**the expected output is**
[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lq4V7.png)

Comment: For the output to be like your picture, look at module `prettytable`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of many possible ways, but the shortest way (and probably least robust) way I could think of, given the text provided in the question:

```
def extract_interface_info(config_text):
    """Returns a list of tuples:
    [(port id, channel-group, switchport mode,vlans),...]
    """
    return [ (interface[0], # port id
              interface[interface.index('channel-group')+1]
                if 'channel-group' in interface else '', 
              interface[interface.index('switchport')+1],
              interface[interface.index('vlan')+1]
             )
             for interface in
             ( interface_str.split()
               for interface_str in config_text.split('interface')
               if 'switchport' in interface_str and 'vlan' in interface_str
              )
            ]
info = extract_interface_info(text)
print('\n'.join(str(interface) for interface in info))
```

prints:

```
('Port-channel2', '', 'trunk', '5,20,30,101,134,201,381')
('GigabitEthernet0/2', '', 'trunk', '5,20,30,101,134,201,381')
('GigabitEthernet1/0', '2', 'trunk', '5,20,30,101,134,201,381')
('GigabitEthernet1/1', '2', 'trunk', '5,20,30,101,134,201,381')
```

I used a generator that splits out the text by the keyword "interface" and filtered the resulting strings by keywords required to appear in the desired sections: 'switchport' and 'vlan'.  Each string meeting the criteria is split by whitespace and fed to the list comprehension statement

The list comprehension statement then puts the desired items from the string into a tuple for each interface and returns a list of those tuples.

Note: channel-group does not appear in all interfaces, so a conditional statement is needed to only look up the index of 'channel-group' if it exists, otherwise, a null str is returned.

Further Note: since this is only a snippet of the file, if 'switchport' and 'vlan' were to occur outside the desired context, this solution would fail in some way, such as including one or more erroneous tuples or raising an IndexError.